# Дни охраны труда - прописная или строчная?

Tags: орфография

Проведение Д(д)ней охраны труда в школе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По правилам русского языка названия постоянно проводимых массовых мероприятий пишутся со строчной буквы: день встречи выпускников, день донора,день открытых дверей, воскресник. Но если это мероприятие имеет общегосударственное значение(или международное) - то с прописной. День охраны труда - общегосударственное - и в школах, и муниципальные, и районные, и областные Дни, значит, с прописной: Проведение Дней охраны труда, Недели охраны труда и т.д.